# What is the correct preposition for searching items?

Tags: prepositions, differences

I am confused about prepositions for searching in [n] count of items.
For example, we have 1000 items, users can search and find an item, but which preposition fits this meaning well?

- Search in 1000 items...
- Search through 1000 items...
- Search among 1000 items...
- Search for 1000 items...
- Search within 1000 items...

Do you have any suggestion that is suitable for a native speaker?

Comment: _Search for 1000 items_ and _Search through/among 1000 items_ convey different meanings. It's not a question of right or wrong.

Comment: If the searcher is looking for _one_ item among a thousand, it's _among_ or _through_.

Comment: Search all one thousand items . . .